# Is there any way to disable/enable the back button?

Tags: buttons

The back button annoys me in some apps so I want to disable it in certain time and will enable it later. Is there any way to do it ?

p/s : I use Galaxy Note 2 N7100 with Android 4.1.2, rooted.

Comment: JatSing, *Is there an app for X* questions are off topic according to our [FAQ]. I took the freedom to slightly re-phrase your question to avoid it from being closed for that reason -- you issue should still be fully reflected ;)

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon when would you like to disable the back button and how would you want to do that.

You can use [AutoInput](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autoinput&hl=en) with [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) to suppress particular keys globally. You would have to create a task with the action Plugin → AutoInput → Modes → Configuration → do the needful.

You can use [Xposed Additions Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spazedog.xposed.additionsgb.pro&hl=en)<sup>[1](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/56561/page-up-and-page-down-in-web-pages-and-elsewhere/118917?s=2|0.4310#118917)</sup> too.

As for an idea of how to disable that button using Task shortcut try [GMD Gesture Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.goodmooddroid.gesturecontrol&hl=en)<sup>[2](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/119001/96277)</sup> or [LMT](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1330150)<sup>[3](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/56561/page-up-and-page-down-in-web-pages-and-elsewhere/119265?s=1|0.2730#119265)</sup>.

Also see my answer for [Is there a way I can prevent the back button from going to the home screen?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/111631/is-there-a-way-i-can-prevent-the-back-button-from-going-to-the-home-screen/111772#111772)

---

<sub>1: Relevant usage: [Xposed Additions Pro](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/118917/96277)

2: Relevant usage: [GMD Gesture Control](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/119001/96277)

3. Relevant usage: [LMT](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/56561/page-up-and-page-down-in-web-pages-and-elsewhere/119265?s=1|0.2730#119265)</sub>

Comment: Note that AutoInput is available only for Android 4.3 and above.