# Page up and page down in web pages and elsewhere

Tags: browser, user-interface

I can't figure out a usable way of scrolling page by page. I'm using Android 4.1 (stock Android from Google). I have root access if needed. I want this especially in the default browser, but a solution that works in all applications would be better.

I've found three ways to scroll down by one page.

- Set my finger down at the bottom of the page, drag it to the top in a vertical line, raise my finger. This is clumsy because it requires a long finger gesture.
- A flicking motion in the up direction. This is clumsy because it requires flicking by the exact amount, otherwise the text scrolls by more or less than one page. I just can't manage that much precision.
- A sufficiently forceful flicking motion, then set my finger down when the text has reached the point where I want it to be. This requires more finger strength than I would like and a lot of visual concentration; my finger-eye coordination is nowhere near enough to succeed with reasonably high probability.

Given how common the “page down” task is, there must be a better way that I'm missing. What is it?

Comment: Something that "works in all applications" will almost certainly be impossible. Unlike desktop apps, which generally tap into a standard UI framework that can handle HID pageup/down events, Android apps can be developed with custom UI setups, and I don't even think that there *is* a pageup/down event in Android (I could definitely be wrong there). However, this is a really interesting question. I bet there are some browsers or browser addons that can give you this functionality, and I'd also love to know if Chrome or the stock browser can do this.

Comment: Actually, I take my "will almost certainly be impossible" comment back. *If* you can spoof a touch event that swipes from bottom to top, that would work in almost any app.

Comment: You mean to scroll from top to bottom(and vice versa) of a page in single vertical scroll/swipe?

Comment: @Lucky No, not from top to bottom. One screenful at a time. Like the PageUp/PageDown keys on a PC-style computer. And a swipe isn't a convenient UI, ideally this would be what the Volume Up/Down keys do in a text viewer such as a web browser.

Comment: @Firelord I'm currently on Cyanogenmod 10 based on Android 4.3. Please make that an answer, this seems to be exactly what I want!

Comment: Gilles, did you try my solution? I have another solution in mind, which wouldn't require you to even press those hardware keys. It would be based on [LMT launcher](http://www.droid-life.com/2013/01/23/lmt-launcher-brings-pie-goodness-without-the-custom-rom/) and Tasker.

Comment: Have you found a solution for 7.0?  Volkey Scroll looks promising but isn't quite there.

Comment: @William I haven't even looked, my phone is stuck on 5.1.

Answer (score 4):

You can use LMT Launcher's PIE navigation feature to achieve your objective. LMT wouldn't replace your current home launcher which means you can rest assured that your home screen would stay untouched.

Let's come to business. [Here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1330150) is the XDA thread about LMT Launcher. It's a **freeware** app and needs to be sideloaded into the system (not available on Play Store). Make sure that [Unknown Sources](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2812853) is enabled before you try installing its APK.

It can be activated along the edges of the screen (I prefer at bottom) like this:

<sub>(Click image to enlarge; Source: Droid Life)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

This navigation is called PIE and each of the blue section is referred as a pie.

## How does it help?

You can configure a pie to execute a script. The script would be nothing more than:

```
su; input touchscreen swipe X1 Y1 X2 Y2
```

where the X1, Y1 and X2, Y2 coordinates can be obtained from my answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/118917/96277) (see step 1 or step 2 under **Instructions for Tasker and Xposed Additions** there).

You can also configure a pie to execute a KeyEvent. The keycode for **Page Up** and **Page Down** are 92 and 93 respectively. See more keycodes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28969112/4720957).

## Usage Instructions

1. Launch LMT launcher and activate it.
2. Go to **Pie → Pie Item 1 → Script** and enter:

   ```
   su; input touchscreen swipe X1 Y1 X2 Y2
   ```

   Replace the coordinates with the one you produced as ideal to simulate **Scroll Down**.
3. Configure  another pie in the manner noted above but interchange the  coordinates to `X2 Y2 X1 Y1` to simulate **Scroll Up**.
4. In place of **Script** you may select **Key** option and enter the keycode you want to be executed.
5. Under **Settings** tab you can configure the settings of navigation system such as the place where you want the bar to show up, size of PIE's inner/outer radius, its color and so on.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

---

I tested my solution successfully on CM12. [Here](https://goo.gl/5Wt2BN) is a short ripped video (~6MB) showing the answer in action.

Comment: This is an impressive answer.  Could this be used to get Page Down to work properly http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/168500/page-down-and-page-up-dont  I'm not sure.

Comment: Sorry Liam, but I do not have an OTG cable or a bluetooth keyboard at my disposal to run tests. Have you tried my other solutions available on this very page?

Comment: I'll mail you a bluetooth keyboard if you think you can get this to work.  I have at least one extra one laying around.  Alternatively you can even go into an Apple Store and reconfigure one of their bluetooth keyboards to work with your phone temporarily.

Comment: My apologies @William, as I'm nowdays short on time to do anything significant or useful for any Android related issue. However, I think I can offer my generosity through a bounty. Please send me a bounty note and all the details you would want in an answer and I will offer a bounty of +150, if that's okay with you.

Answer (score 3):

The old but good question. Answering it to myself, I came up with using [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) alone for this. At least now volume up/down scrolls one page in Chrome. The method might be applied either to another program or to other options inside MacroDroid, for example buttons on screen:

- Trigger: Volume Up/Down, might reguire giving MacroDroid accessebility permissions.
- Action: Gesture [300 ms, 500, 1850-> 500,340]. My device has 1980 pixel height, so this values should be adjusted to the device/application.
- Constraint: Chrome appliction in foreground. Other application often also might be used for this macro, but different screen layout might prevent from working correctly. For example, Quora has a toolbar at the bottom of the page, so I will probably need to create a separate macro for it.

Answer (score 1):

[Hacker's Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard) has Page Up/Down keys which default browser and Chrome handles properly. You can even make it appear outside of input context with "Use permanent notification" option. That doesn't help much since having keyboard open all the time is a bit absurd, but proves the point that an app for having global Page Up/Down could exist.

PS. Dolphin browser also has an option for mapping Volume Up/Down to scroll by page and that's what I'm trying to use right now.

Comment: Mapping the Volume keys in Dolphin Browser is for version 10.x per https://dolphinbrowser.desk.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1249750-which-dolphin-versions-support-the-dolphin-key-?b_id=317 and said version is no longer available. Pooh.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody brought up a physical keyboard. So that.

If you have root access, [Tasker](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/) can do  down button presses even without auto-input. This is still relevant for Android 4.4.4. I could get this to send a page down button, but it has peculiar triggers, like headset volume or media buttons.

The [Button Savior (Root)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smart.swkey) app is promising, but I don't have a rooted device. Did not go anywhere with this, because it seems to not send the keystrokes to the active app.

[Firelord's Aug 25 solution](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/120294/44325) is better.

Comment: I hadn't brought up a physical keyboard because I do not consider carrying one in my pocket to be a viable option. What's “tasker”?

Comment: Tasker is an android automation app. Has all sorts of triggers you could use to do this, and it has function that can send a sequence of down keystrokes, if you have root. I think you should start with button savior.(I can't yet because I don't have root) sorry I realize this is a two year old question and you might have the answer, but I can't find it yet. It's annoying to not be able to do something so basic.

Comment: I have tried an external keyboard and page down buttons don't work

Answer (score 1):

It isn't available in the Stock Android Browser or not even in Chrome. But UC Browser provides this functinality of scrolling exactly one page at a time. You can use the "Scroll Buttons" or "Tap to scroll" or the "Volume keys" feature by installing UC Browser for Android. In the UC browser Settings page you can do configure the scroll style and it resembles the same `Page Up` & `Page Down` key actions like we do in our desktop keyboards.

**Scroll Buttons:** A virtual Page Up and Page Down arrow buttons are added at the right hand side of a webpage.

**Tap to scroll:**
You can either tap at the top half of the screen or th bottom half of the screen to exactly scroll one screen page at a time.

**Volume Keys:** You can also use your volume rocker keys to scroll the screen page one by one. Pressing the Volume down scrolls the page once downwards and pressing Volume up scroll the page once upwards.

For enabling this feature,

- Install [UC browser - Surf it Fast](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.UCMobile.intl) from the Play Store
- Goto Settings > Browsing Settings > Scroll Options
- Either set it to "Scroll Buttons" or "Tap to scroll" or "Volume buttons" > Press Ok
- Now open any scrollable webpage and do the desired action based on your scroll settings. For example:

  1. If you've enabled "Tap to Scroll", then click at the bottom half of the screen to scroll down by one screen page(similar to Page Down key).
  2. Similiarly you can scroll to the top by tapping once at the top half of the screen on any scrollable webpage.

[image: UCBrowser_Scroll_Settings_options]

<sup>Screenshot - UCBrowser Scroll Settings (Click to enlarge image)</sup>

***Note:*** You can also enable all the three options at once. But I recommend to use the "Scroll Buttons" option as it is easy to use and works fine for all pages. In Tap to scroll, clicking link will open the links and will not scroll the page up/down. So tap an area where there are no links available.

Answer (score 1):

The need of using an Xposed module can be removed from my answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/118917/96277). We can use [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) and a very useful plugin named  [AutoInput](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autoinput) to simulate page up/down using Volume keys.

## Instructions

1. Install both the apps.
2. Go to **Settings  →  Accessibility** and enable **Services** for both **Tasker** and **AutoInput**.
3. Launch Tasker. Under **Tasks**, create a task  named **Scroll Up**.
4. Create following actions in that task (`A` implies an action):

   - A1:

     - **Plugin  →  AutoInput  →  Modes  →  Configuration → Key Suppress → Enable → Keys** →  scroll to select **Volume Up**
     - **Timeout**: None

     We're suppressing the Volume Key so that you don't end up with system  ringer volume dialog with a slider when you press that key.
   - A2:

     - **Code  →  Run Shell**:
     - **Command**: `input touchscreen swipe X2 Y2 X1 Y1` or `input keyevent 92`

       If you choose the former command, then use [my answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/118917/96277) to get the coordinates.
     - Check **Use Root**
5. Create another task  named **Scroll Down**.
6. Create following actions in that task:

   - A1:

     - **Plugin → AutoInput → Modes → Configuration → Key Suppress → Enable → Keys** →  scroll to select **Volume Down**
     - **Timeout**: None
   - A2:

     - **Code → Run Shell**:
     - **Command**: `input touchscreen swipe X1 Y1 X2 Y2` or `input keyevent 93`
     - Check **Use Root**
7. Under **Profiles** tab, create two profiles named **Autoinput Up Key** and **Autoinput Down Key**.
8. Link the tasks **Scroll Up** in **Autoinput Up Key** and **Scroll Down** in **Autoinput Down Key** profile.
9. Create a third task named **Launch Profiles** and create following actions in it:

   - A1:

     - **Tasker → Profile Status** →  choose using lens icon **Autoinput Up Key**
     - **Set**: On
   - A2:

     - **Tasker → Profile Status** →  choose using lens icon **Autoinput Down Key**
     - **Set**: On
10. Create the final task named **Kill Profiles** and create the identical actions of step 10. Change **Set** from `On` to `Off` in both actions for this step. We need this task so that the custom actions meant for Volume keys doesn't affect other apps where the keys should function as normal.
11. Create a profile based on application context and select an app of your choice, such as Chrome.
12. Link **Launch Profiles** task in Chrome profile.
13. Link **Kill Profiles** as an exit task in Chrome profile.

You may now launch Chrome. Use Volume Up/Down to find that they would not change the ringer volume but would scroll up/down the page you've opened up in Chrome. Switch to another app not selected in above steps or close Chrome and those hardware keys would function as normal.

---

**Note:** It's not butter smooth as my linked answer but it's not sluggish either. If you're not comfortable with Xposed framework or modules then this answer would help for sure.

We're good to go!

Answer (score 0):

UC Browser has two kinds of tap scrolling.  You can configure it to scroll up if you hit a non-link portion in the upper half of the screen or vice versa to scroll down.  You can also elect to display two arrow buttons (that you can drag around the screen so you can position them to your liking) for tap to scroll.

You can get it here:  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.UCMobile.intl

Note:  As I write this, the UC Browser HD (specifically for tablets) does NOT have this capability.

Answer (score 0):

[Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) allows creation of [Scenes](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/scenes.html). We can use scenes to create virtual buttons on the screen which can work as navigational keys to scroll up/down/left/right on the screen.

This answer would make good use of all of my earlier answers written on this page. It goes without saying that root access would be needed than.

<sub>(Some mundane scenes I created; click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

<sub>(Excuse the drawing because I'm no good in it and neither I've tasted the power of scenes yet. Nevertheless, you can see how they are acting as navigational keys.)</sub>

## Instructions for creating Scenes

1. Install and launch Tasker
2. Go to **Scenes** tab and create a new scene named **Nav Buttons**.
3. See Image 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. **Note** that you need not to bother about where the scene would show up on the screen since we would configure it later. Simply decide how much space your Scene should be taking on the screen.
4. Under **Tap** create an action that you want to execute when the associated element is touched. You may choose to select an already existing task which may page up or swipe down the displayed app's page. See my answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/118917/96277) to know how to create swipe up/down tasks or see [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/120294/96277) to see KeyEvents which can do page up/down.
5. **Optional**: If you want to destroy the scene from inside the scene then you may consider adding an action under **Long Tap** to kill the scene or the app.

   - Scene can be destroyed using the action **Scene → Destroy Scene →** select the Scene using lens icon.
   - Alternatively, if you decide to create an app from this Scene (later on the app creation part) then create the action **Code → Run Shell**,

     - **Command**: `am force-stop <PKG_NAME>`

       Create a unique `<PKG_NAME>`, such as `com.user.android.se` and keep it noted somewhere since we would need it in app creation.
     - Check **Use Root**
6. See Image 8, 9, 10, 11.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge; hover to know details)</sub>

[image: IMG: 1]
[image: IMG: 2]
[image: IMG: 3]
[image: IMG: 4]
[image: IMG: 5]
[image: IMG: 6]
[image: IMG: 7]
[image: IMG: 8]
[image: IMG: 9]
[image: IMG: 10]
[image: IMG: 11]
[image: IMG: 12]
[image: IMG: 13]
[image: IMG: 14]

---

Now, at this point **we have multiple choices to proceed with the scene**. You may,

1. Continue to use Tasker and create a profile where you want the scene to show up,
2. Use [LMT Launcher](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1330150)'s PIE navigation to use the Tasker shortcut in a pie. See my answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/119265/96277) to know how to use LMT Launcher. This approach would allow you to show/hide the scene at your will, at any place in system, and doesn't need a Tasker profile to work.
3. Use [Xposed Additions Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spazedog.xposed.additionsgb.pro) or [AutoInput](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autoinput) or [QuickClick](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.blor.quickclickgold) to show/hide that scene based on a Volume key press. See my [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/118917/96277)  for Xposed Additions Pro's usage or try AutoInput using [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/120294/96277).
4. Use an app like [GMD Gesture Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.goodmooddroid.gesturecontrol) to show/hide the scene based on screen gestures. The freedom is same as one granted for LMT Launcher. See [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/119001/96277) to know its usage.
5. You can use some automation apps like [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) to show/hide the scene if they allow launching a Tasker shortcut (I know, why bother doing that, but wait for more!)

## Or

You may use [Tasker App Factory](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.appfactory) to transform a task into a full-fledged standalone app (read: **Tasker independent**) which can be sideloaded into system just like any other app and would work as if you're executing a task using Tasker itself.

The good part is that app creation using Tasker and Tasker App Factory  is legal, so one can distribute it at his/her own will.

You want more! Right. **The biggest hurdle of depending upon commercial apps is pretty much solved in this particular case.** If you do not own or do not want to buy Tasker but a person known to you has it, then you may kindly request that person to create an app for you. You may stick to the basic approach needed for navigational buttons mentioned in the current answer or give a chance to your own imagination.

Also, one more goodie. You can use that new app with any of the five options that I've listed for a Tasker scene. **I've successfully tested all of them.**

## Create an app from a task in Tasker

1. Install Tasker App Factory
2. Under **Tasks** tab touch and hold your task entry and tap the three dotted line → **Export → As App**.
3. Create a unique package name for the app, such as `com.unique.package.name`.

   **Note** that if you completed **Long Tap** step during Scene creation then you must use the same package name here.
4. You would see app creation detail. Try the icons at the bottom. The Android icon would initiate sideloading the newly created app using Android's Package Installer.

   The app, once created, would be saved under  `Tasker/factory/kids/` which is located in your default storage.

   Also, the name of the app (seen in launcher after installation) and its icon would be same as the name of the Task and icon you selected in the task creation under Tasker.

[image: IMG: 1]
[image: IMG: 2]
[image: IMG: 3]

---

I've created a demo app based on the current answer, hosted on my Google Drive. Find it [here](https://goo.gl/MkMtiQ). The permissions it require are:

<sub>(Superuser permission isn't listed but is definitely required.)</sub>

[image: IMG: 1]

<sub>(App icon made by [Freepik](http://www.flaticon.com/authors/freepik) from [Flaticon](http://www.flaticon.com), is licensed under [CC BY 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/))</sub>

There's is a slight problem here. While I was able to successfully test my app independently on my secondary Lollipop ROMs on the same device with same resolution, the app didn't work satisfactorily on my other but low resolution device. Oh well, what can I do!