# Any way to scroll browser or page w/ volume buttons?

Tags: applications, browser, 8.1-oreo, nexus-6p

I"m using Oreo on a Nexus 6p, and read online a lot. Is there any way *without rooting* that a web browser can scroll or page with the volume buttons?

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/56561/96277

Comment: Not when the reviews for the app include "Buggy when switching to recent apps on volkey enabled apps", "Simply non-functional, waste of time", "Very buggy, doesn't scroll up, in chrome is hit or miss, same on feed...", and "Jittery. More effort than scrolling".